# Error Checking in CGContextDrawImage

Tags: ios, cgcontextdrawimage

I am trying to draw a png image into a view. I tried copying the code from other sources. Absolutely nothing gets drawn.

I inserted code to draw a background and doodles and that appears fine. Image draw. Nothing. It's reading the file because the image dimensions get filled in correctly.

I am missing some error checks?

The other possibility is that I am drawing entirely outside the view.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect drawrect ;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([imagePath UTF8String]) ;
    if (provider)
    {
        CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        drawrect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0) ;
        drawrect.size = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth (image), CGImageGetHeight(image)) ;

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, CGImageGetHeight(image));
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, drawrect, image) ;
        CGImageRelease (image) ;
        CFRelease (provider) ;
   }
]
```

Comment: Nil check your `imagePath`.

Comment: The code works for me.

Comment: The image path gets checked earlier.